# logrotating files in a directories and its subdirectories

Tags: logrotate, recursive, directory

Is it possible to get `logrotate` to consider logfiles in a directory and all its subdirectories?  (i.e. without explicitly listing the subdirectories.)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

How deep do your subdirectories go?

```
/var/log/basedir/*.log /var/log/basedir/*/*.log {
    daily
    rotate 5
}
```

Will rotate all **.log** files in basedir/ as well as all **.log** files in any direct child of basedir. If you also need to go 1 level deeper just add another `/var/log/basedir/*/*/*.log` until you have each level covered.

This can be tested by using a separate logrotate config file which contains a constraint that will not be met (a high minsize) and then running log rotate yourself in verbose mode

```
logrotate -d testconfig.conf
```

the -d flag will list each log file it is considering to rotate.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like `-d` puts logrotate in dry run mode (i.e. doesn't actually change anything) actually.

Comment: Not really directly relevant but probably useful to someone.  the `-f` option tells logrotate to "force run".  a bare word at the end of the command is a config file to use instead of the default.  so `logrotate -f /some/config` means run with that config file, and always run even if the config file says it's not time to run yet.  To my untrained eyes, and to my predecessor who put in a cron job with that, it seemed like `-f` was just specifying the config file.  Quite confusing.

Comment: it's actually _debug_ `-d, --debug    Turns on debug mode and implies -v.  In debug mode, no changes will be made to the logs  or  to  the  logrotate state file.`

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the depth of subdirectories can change without warning, so I set up a bash script to find all subdirectories and create a config entry for each directory.

It's also important for me to keep the structure of subdirectories after rotation, which wildcards (i.e. @DanR's answer) didn't seem to do. If you're doing daily log rotations, you could put this script in a daily cron-job.

```sh
basedir=/var/log/basedir/
#destdir=${basedir} # if you want rotated files in the same directories
destdir=/var/log/archivedir/ #if you want rotated files somewhere else
config_file=/wherever/you/keep/it
> ${config_file} #clear existing config_file contents

subfolders = $(find ${basedir} -type d)

for ii in ${subfolders}
do
    jj=${ii:${#basedir}} #strip off basedir, jj is the relative path

    #append new entry to config_file
    echo "${basedir}${jj}/* {
        olddir ${destdir}${jj}/
        daily
        rotate 5
    }" >> ${config_file}

    #add one line as spacing between entries
    echo "\n" >> ${config_file}

    #create destination folder, if it doesn't exist
    [ -d ${destdir}${jj} ] || mkdir ${destdir}${jj}
done
```

Like @DanR suggested, test with `logrotate -d`

Answer (score 5):

It's old thread, but you can do the following:

```
/var/log/basedir/**/*.log {
    daily
    rotate 5
}
```

These two stars will match zero or more directories. You must be careful, though, how you define log files to be rotated, because you can rotate files that have been already rotated. I'll cite the manual of logrotate here.

> Please use wildcards with caution.  If you specify *, logrotate will rotate all files, including previously rotated ones.  A way around this is to use the olddir directive or a more exact wildcard (such as *.log).

Comment: this wildcard pattern did not work for me. Logrotate 3.8.6 on RHEL 7.3

Comment: Maybe you should enable `globstar` before running logrotate. This will enable it for bash `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: I have the same problem. Logrotate 3.8.7 on Ubuntu 16.04.3. ls /var/log/basedir/**/*.log works as described, but logrotate doesn't.

Comment: doesn't work for me either, on logrotate 3.11.0. I don't think that bash expansion has anything to do with logrotate wildcards. (except for similar syntax)

Comment: Not working. Please remove this answer or add a version where it dóes work.

Comment: Not working even for me.

Comment: I wish it worked, but it does not. Even if `globstar` is enabled. Its a long standing open issue - https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

Took some trial and error but finally got my wildcard pattern working as I have log files in one folder followed by IP and then hostname and then actual log folder.

I have a second hard drive as a VM so I pointed the logs to use this path:

/mnt/logs/var/log/remotes/10.4.11.12/pve2-test

I have several remote servers listed in the remotes folder followed by it's host name in it's own folder.  I didn't want to change this structure so figured out how to use the wildcard that actually works.

/mnt/logs/var/log/remotes/1*/**/*.log

I've tried /mnt/logs/var/log/remotes /** /** /*.log which didn't work.  I am guessing because I was trying to do full wildcard followed with another full wildcard which it didn't like. (Pardon the extra spaces in the wildcard as it truncated in editing??)

Hope this helps.