# How do you rotate Apache logs on Linux (centos)?

Tags: apache-2.2

This might be a simple question. How do you rotate Apache logs daily?

Comment: Why the down vote? isn't this a valid questions?

Comment: Mary - I can't speak for the downvoter, but my guess is that the downvote was because this is something that is easily discoverable by a simple Google search, and you showed no evidence that you had tried to research it yourself.

Comment: In her defence, this is what I found by a simple Google search.

Answer (score 9):

Put the below lines into `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd`:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    daily
    rotate 7
    postrotate
        /sbin/service httpd reload > /var/log/httpd/rotate 2>&1 || true
    endscript
    compress
}
```

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/208006/logrotating-files-in-a-directories-and-its-subdirectories if you want to do this for more than one log directory.

Answer (score 4):

On a Linux system you would usually setup [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

You could also use something like [cronolog](http://cronolog.org/).

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps a bit more elegant to use the Apache 'rotatelogs' program, imo.

Here's an example from one of my servers:

```
# Seo logs, rotated daily, on GMT clock
LogFormat "%h %t %D \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{Host}i" seo
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/seo_log.%Y%m%d 86400" seo
```

You can also set a GMT offset for localtime, or specify rotation based on filesize.

'man rotatelogs'.