# can logrotate process all *.log in a directory tree?

Tags: logrotate

Logrotate can work on individual files or wildcarded files (*.log, for example) in a specified directory, but does it inherently have the ability to traverse a directory tree of arbitrary depth and process files it finds?

thanx

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/questions/208006/logrotating-files-in-a-directories-and-its-subdirectories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You can wildcard the directories though so if your tree has a small-ish known depth you could do something like:

```
   /a/* /a/*/* /a/*/*/*  {
       rotate 5
       weekly
   }
```

If you only have logs at the leaf only `/a/*/*/*` is needed.

> "Please use wildcards with caution.  If you specify `*`, logrotate will rotate all files, including previously  rotated  ones.   A way  around this is to use the `olddir` directive or a more exact wildcard (such as `*.log`)" -- logrotate man page